# Branch free saturation

Tags: bit-manipulation, branch

I have the following calculation:

```
 unsigned int a;
 unsigned b = (a < 4) ? a : 4;
```

Is it possible to convert the second line to a branch free format?

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your processor architecture (also: possibly your compiler, compiler settings), the above source code  may already result in branch-free code and has the advantage of being very readable. I would suggest checking the disassembled object code to find out whether that is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  b = (a >= 4) * 4 + (a < 4) * ((a >> 1) & 1) * 2 + (a < 4) * (a & 1);
```

Explanation: we are returning 4 by "zeroing" the 2 least significant bits if a >= 4. If a < 4, we use these 2 least significant bits.

Comment: Hows about simply       b = (a >=4) * 4 + (a <4) * (a&3)    ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a conditionally applied mask:

```
unsigned int a, b, t, m;
t = a - 4;
m = 0 - ((int)t < 0); // mask of all 0s or all 1s
b = (t & m) + 4; // mask all 1s: b=a-4+4;  mask all 0s: b=4
```